# Como quitar estilos con jQuery al dar click a un elemento HTML

Tags: jquery

Mi Pregunta en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   $('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    $("#categoria").find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");                
      });
```

Comment: $("#categoria").find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg"); este codigo me quita todos los estilos de una sola vez y me gustaria que se le quite solo al que se le de el click unicamente

Comment: El problema es que en `find(".cont-optionElement")` estas utilizando el selector de clase y por lo tanto te esta retornando todos los elementos que contienen esa clase especifica. Deberias indicar especificamente la posición en el array del elemento del que deseas eliminar la clase, ejemplo si fuese el primer elemento ...`$(find(".cont-optionElement")[0])`...

Comment: todos esos elementos tienen identificador ya veras

Comment: Esto lo genera un while

Comment: <div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento ".$contador."' iden='".$contador."' >". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</div>";

Comment: Es decir; que cada div tiene un identificador y si lo relaciono con lo que tu me indicas, me haces pensar que deberia meter este identificador : var identificador = $(this).attr("iden"); dentro de una variable php

Comment: Mira aqui esta un ejemplo de lo que te menciono: https://jsfiddle.net/38zwrbbo/

Comment: Lo que quieres es cambiar el estilo de la "X" ? @gam

Comment: no; mas bien que la X remueva el estilo que tiene su selector

Comment: trate con esto: $("#categoria",this).find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");

Comment: pero el this no se como; se utiliza en este metodo

Comment: El codigo que me distes funciona pero tendria que poner todas las posiciones; tendria que ver si con este $("#categoria",this).find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass‌​("estilSelectCateg")‌​--Funciona? o usar el contador para ponerlo como posiciones para susplantar [0]

Comment: Lo mas simple que se me ocurre es que ambos elementos (las X y las "Tropas al maximo") en su contenedores tengan el mismo index (posicion) para que sepas a cual elemento quitar en ambos casos. https://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1):

Para remover clases de alguna posición de array, igual puedes usar:

```
eq(5).removeClass('selected');
```

Así te ahorras el `find` y te selecciona todos los elementos, si no, solo el que le especifica en concreto. De todos modos lo puedes combinar con `index(this)`, para poder saber la posición del elemento  que accede.

Puedes usarlo como:

```
if(imagenActual.index() != 5)
```

Te dejo un enlace donde lo utilizan en un ejercicio guardándolo en una variable [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: como seria el de index ?

Comment: voy  a intentar pasar el contador desde jquery a php pero en este caso como se pasan estas variables

Comment: Como opinión personal si usas un lenguaje del lado del servidor para solucionar esto le agregaras complejidad innecesaria.

Answer (score 1):

aun no estoy tan seguro de entender tu problema pero checa este snipped y ejecutalo.

Como te mencione primero selecionamos todos los elementos, les agregamos un identificador y luego lo clonamos de tal forma que el clon tenga este mismo identificador.

Luego agregamos escuchadores de eventos al click de ambos conjuntos de elementos y al hacer click buscamos en su contenedor contraparte y removemos la clase a sus elementos padre y asi mismos.

Es bonito usar jQuery solo para lo necesario, saludos

```js
$().ready(function(){
/* selecionamos todas las acciones */
var acciones = document.querySelectorAll(".accion");
 
for(let i=0, accion; accion = acciones[i]; i++) {
/* le agregamos un identificador */
  accion.dataset.indice = i;
  /* las clonamos, el identificador se clona tambien */
  $(accion.parentNode).clone().appendTo("#etiquetas");
}

$("#etiquetas").on("click",".accion", function(){
/* buscamos su correspondiente accion */
 var selector = "#acciones [data-indice='" + this.dataset.indice + "']";
 let accion = document.querySelector(selector);
 accion.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
 this.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
});

$("#acciones").on("click",".accion", function(){
/* buscamos su correspondiente etiqueta*/
 var selector = "#etiquetas [data-indice='" + this.dataset.indice + "']";
 let accion = document.querySelector(selector);
 accion.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
 this.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
});

});
```

```css
.active {
   background-color: red;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .accion {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  }
  .item { padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acciones" style='min-height:100px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px'>
 <div class="active item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="accion">Ganar el juego</a>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="accion">Rendirce</a>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="accion">Salir</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="etiquetas" style='height:100px; border:1px solid red;'> </div>
```